# How do I extract the base URI?

Tags: java

I have a bunch of URIs (`Strings`) like this:

```
METRICS.COMPANY.APP1
METRICS.COMPANY.APP1.TOTAL.90DAY
METRICS.COMPANY.APP1.TOTAL.WEEKLY
METRICS.COMPANY.APP1.TOTAL.MONTHLY
METRICS.COMPANY.APP2
METRICS.COMPANY.APP2.TOTAL.90DAY
METRICS.COMPANY.APP2.TOTAL.WEEKLY
METRICS.COMPANY.APP2.TOTAL.MONTHLY
METRICS.BUSINESS.DECISIONS
METRICS.BUSINESS.DECISIONS.MONTHLY
METRICS.BUSINESS.DECISIONS.ANNUALLY
METRICS.EMPLOYEE
METRICS.EMPLOYEE.WEEKLY
```

Is there a way I can extract the unique "base" URI from each set of similar URIs? That is, I am interested in only getting:

```
METRICS.COMPANY.APP1
METRICS.COMPANY.APP2
METRICS.BUSINESS.DECISIONS
METRICS.EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: One way would be `if(s.endsWith(".WEEKLY")) s = s.substring(s.length() - 7);` and so on...

Comment: I feel there's an awesome algorithm that can solve this.

Comment: Can you give more context over the words combination. Eg. TOTAL is always before WEEKLY/MONTHLY/90DAY/ANNUALLY else it will be WEEKLY/MONTHLY/90DAY/ANNUALLY.

Comment: I don't think a good solution would depend on particular strings.

Comment: What do you mean, context independent algorithm? Hope you have one.

Comment: I obviously mean a generic one.

Comment: Correct but if we have less values, then we can do this using a regular expression. No need to go for a lot multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data will be ordered, like it is in your example, thus assuming the base will always appear before its children, this is what I came up with:

```
private static Collection<String> extractBases(String[] nodes) {
    Arrays.sort(nodes); // optional, to ensure order

    Deque<String> bases = new ArrayDeque<>();
    bases.addFirst(nodes[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (!nodes[i].contains(bases.peekFirst())) { // if it's not a child
            bases.addFirst(nodes[i]);
        }
    }

    return bases;
}
```

You can check a demo with your input here: http://ideone.com/sjEfvc

Comment: Yup! Edited to use a `Deque` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: And also added the sorting step.